# Count total number of object within object

Tags: jquery, size

After print an object data.allDueDateObj  on console I am getting data like

```
[Object { vaccineName="MMR",  dueDate="2015-09-30T18:00:00Z"}, Object { vaccineName="Influenza",  dueDate="2015-11-30T18:00:00Z"}, Object { vaccineName="Typhoid",  dueDate="2016-02-29T18:00:00Z"}, Object { vaccineName="Meningococcal ACWY",  dueDate="2016-07-31T18:00:00Z"}]
```

Now I am counting total how many object in data.allDueDateObj .

Comment: Can you post the actual object, instead of its console representation. From what you have, it looks like the syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property

```
data.allDueDateObj.length
```

Comment: Just a question is his array a valid one?

Comment: @pekka yes! The posted one is the console representation. Although OP has posted key value pairs with `=`. That is where you doubt right.

Comment: I still get confused with a valid and invalid one so i had to ask @Jai thank you for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   data.allDueDateObj.length;
```